# How do I manually physically delete a page from a Word file itself?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I am trying to delete a stubborn blank page.

Tried  showing  ¶).  and deleting.

Tried go to page and deleting.

Tried selecting everything on the page and deleting.

What I am asking to do is how can a manually edit the file e.g. hex editor to delete this last page

Comment: Do you know how this page got to be "stubborn" like that?  What's on it?  What's before it and after it?  ***Exactly what happens when you try to delete it?***  Can you copy it and paste it into another document?  Can you then delete it from the second document?  Can you copy your *entire* document, paste it into a new, blank document, and then delete the "stubborn" page?

Comment: Any chance the document has a defined page structure (like say a booklet or double-sided format), where the page is required as a placeholder?  Is there a page break on the previous page?  After doing your deletion attempts, did you close the document and re-open it?  Are there any "layers" on the previous page, like a picture or chart plus text?  Load another compatible word processor (like the free LibreOffice Writer), open the file, and see what you see and how it behaves.